# change laravel blade css class by the amount of objects

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

first of all, the question is not about the solution, but about the best practice.

my blade is:

```
@if (!empty($amount))
     <div class="amount {{$color}}">
          {{$amount}}
     </div>
@endif
```

color class is defined in service by amount. But I can bet, that is bad architectural solution.

So I need an advice for the best practice in laravel for customizing blade class.

Comment: this is bad? im using this technique. it's interesting if anyone can make a better suggestions.

Comment: what about using custom laravel directive?

Comment: thanks for that Martynas, but im still just using it like so: @ php $bgcolor = {{ $record->amount ? 'success' : 'danger' }} @ endphp    then   <div class="bg-{{$bgcolor}}"></div> . so this will suffice for now since it is not that complicated. i think that you shouldnt feel guilty using this technique if the logic was very simple (wink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would calculate the color level (`$color` in your example) where you assign `$amount` to the blade template (most likely in a controller). You can do this with `if/elseif/else` where you set colors depending on your limits (e.g. `$amount < 5` is green, `$amount < 10` is orange, `$amount < 20` is red).

It is best practice to separate design from logic, therefore I won't recommend to add logic to you blade template - even if it is a one-liner.

If that's the way you have it right now then I'd keep it this way.

Comment: data is assigned in view composer. So I added additional parameter there. But I have another tricky question - where I should put method to return that class name by amount (e.g. $amount < 5 is green, $amount < 10 is orange, $amount < 20 is red) ?

Comment: I'm a big fan of the "Repository Design Pattern". For example I have a `UserController` and respectively a `UserRepository`. So my controller has a function call to the `UserRepository` (`$userRepository->calculateSomething()`) and nothing more. I have almost no logic in my controllers - everything is in my repositories.

Comment: but what if you're inside the foreach loop on the blade file?

Comment: In the blade foreach-loop you are outputting data for each element of a (hopefully previously prepared and to the view assigned) array/object. It doesn't matter if you have one or many colors. It only depends on your data structure.